# Pass cURL POST Nested JSON to cURL GET

Tags: curl, jq

I have a working POST request in shell script post.sh:

```bsh
curl -s --location --request POST \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json'. \
     --data '{"password": "'$(echo $PW)'"}'. \
     https://api-sec.path/managed-vault/login/myuser
```

Which returns json containing: `"auth":{"client_token":"my.token"}`

`post.sh | jq .auth.client_token` returns "my.token"

I want to pass this to another independently working GET request (get.sh):

```bsh
TOKEN=$(cat)

curl --location --request GET \
     --header 'X-Vault-Token: '$(echo $TOKEN)''
     https://api-sec.path/managed-secrets/myuser
```

Manually pasting the TOKEN works: `get.sh sQ34my./toKeN//z`

This returns an error saying my token was wrong:

```bsh
post.sh | jq .auth.client_token | get.sh
```

How do I fix this piped curl output?

Comment: You read the  `$TOKEN` in you get.sh script as a command line parameter. You should read it from standard output, because that is how you provide it to the script via pipe `| `. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/how-to-read-from-a-file-or-standard-input-in-bash.

Comment: So something like `TOKEN=$(cat /dev/stdin)` ? This doesn't work.

Comment: Just `TOKEN=$(cat)`. I made a test script and it worked for me.

Comment: I get `{"errors":["permission denied"]}` returned when I use `TOKEN=$(cat)` as @nobody suggests. But again, passing in the token manually with `TOKEN=$1` works. Perhaps a newline character is messing it up? Or the quotes? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to use two separate shell scripts, `post.sh` and `get.sh`.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# This is post.sh

curl -s --location --request POST \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data "$( jo password="$PW" )" \
     'https://api-sec.path/managed-vault/login/myuser'
```

I've used `jo` here to create the JSON payload, ensuring that the password    is properly encoded. To use `jq` instead, replace only the `jo` command with

```bsh
jq --arg password "$PW" -n '{ password: $password }'
```

Do not inject the shell variable `PW` directly into the JSON document, as doing so creates a code injection vulnerability, and additionally requires you to encode the password string separately.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# This is get.sh

token=$( ./post.sh | jq -r '.auth.client_token' )

curl --location --request GET \
     --header "X-Vault-Token: $token" \
     'https://api-sec.path/managed-secrets/myuser'
```

The `get.sh` script simply calls `post.sh` (which is assumed to be located in the current directory), parses out the token from the response and assigns it to the `token` shell variable.

You could still read the token from standard input in `get.sh` if you so wished.  The following assumes that the token is delivered on a single line:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# This is get.sh

if [ -t 0 ]; then
    printf 'Enter token: ' >&2
fi
IFS= read -r token

curl --location --request GET \
     --header "X-Vault-Token: $token" \
     'https://api-sec.path/managed-secrets/myuser'
```

This script would prompt you for the token if its standard input is connected directly to a terminal.  If not, you get no prompt.

You would call this variant of `get.sh` as

```bsh
./post.sh | jq -r '.auth.client_token' | ./get.sh
```

---

There are a few issues with your code:

1. In your first script, `$PW` is used unquoted.  This means that the password would be split into multiple words on spaces, tabs, and newlines.  Each word would then undergo filename globbing. This would be problematic if you used passwords with e.g. spaces and filename globbing characters such as `*`, `[`, and `?`.  You have the same issue in the second script with regards to the `TOKEN` variable.
2. Using `$(echo $variable)` in place of just `$variable` is an anti-pattern with several issues (unquoted variable expansion and the fact that `echo` might modify the contents of the string if it contains backslash escapes).
3. As already mentioned, the way you construct your JSON document may easily break the formatting of the document if the password contains characters like double quotes or literal tabs etc. You will need to quote the password properly and I've shown two ways of doing that above (using the handy `jo` tool and the `jq` utility that you're already using).
4. `jq` will, by default, output JSON encoded strings.  When you call `jq` to get your token, you'll get it as a JSON string which will include a set of double quotes.  Using `jq` with its `-r` (`--raw-output`) option will ensure that you get the token as a decoded string.

Comment: `jq -r` solved my issue and all these tips for sanitizing json are much appreciated